# Link-local IPv4 network scope on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ipv4, mdns, link-local

We have an embedded PC that initially starts off life with a link-local IPv4 address, typically 169.254.0.1. It broadcasts its existence using Zeroconf using the python-zeroconf library. These Zeroconf messages are happily received on the Mac, but the ZeroConf broadcast is never received on Windows 10 unless the PC is also on a link-local address too.

Is this a limitation of Windows, or is there a setting that allows Windows to communicate with other link-local addresses on the network even when assigned a static IP address?

Comment: Zeroconf isn't an actual protocol. What exactly is your program actually doing?

Comment: I cannot ping Link-local addresses on Windows 10 unless the Windows laptop is also on a link local address. The strange thing is that some Windows PCs work, some don't. I'm trying to work out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a third-party mDNS resolver such as Bonjour for Windows to enable support in Win32. And check this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1330027/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-10-build-17134/1330028#1330028).